# Matplotlib pcolor not plotting correctly

Tags: matplotlib, heatmap

I am trying to create a heat map from a DataFrame (df) of IDs (rows) and Positions (columns) at which a motif is possible. If the motif is present the value of the table is 1 and 0 if it is not present. Such as:

```
ID  Position 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...etc
A            0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
B            1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
C            0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0
D            1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
```

I then multiply this matrix by itself to find the number of times the motifs present co-occur with motifs at other positions using the code:

```
df.T.dot(df)
```

To obtain the Data Frame:

```
POS 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
1   2 0 2 0 1 0 1 1 1 0
2   0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 
3   2 0 2 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 
4   0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0
5   1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
6   0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 
7   1 0 1 1 0 0 2 0 2 0
8   1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
9   1 0 1 1 0 0 2 0 2 0
10  0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
...
```

Which is symmetrical with the diagonal, however when I try to create the Heat Map using

```
pylab.pcolor(df)
```

It gives me an asymmetrical map that does not seem to be representing the dotted matrix. I don't have enough reputation to post an image though.

Does anyone know why this might be occurring? Thanks

Comment: can you post a link to it and then I can edit your post to insert it?

Comment: That, or just provide a repr of the numpy array, so that we can plot it ourselves. Thanks @user2587593